# One-line for zipping folder in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I'm looking for the equivalent PowerShell command for:

```
tar -zcvf tar-archive-name.tar.gz source-folder
```

Does such a one-liner exist that creates a zip file from a folder recursively adding the contents of the `source-folder`, that doesn't require a 3rd party library like 7-zip?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with [Powershell 5](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/08/13/new-feature-in-powershell-5-compress-files/), you can use the built-in [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/Compress-Archive?view=powershell-5.1) command:

```
Compress-Archive -Path source-folder -DestinationPath archive-name.zip
```

If you are using powershell prior to version 5, there is no one liner solution without a third party program like 7-zip. However, you can leverage the built in zipping capabilities of windows explorer as exposed through the [COM Shell object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to build your own powershell function to do this. [This page outlines the details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daiken/archive/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget.aspx) on how to do so.

Comment: @F505 you can now do it in PS directly, see the updated answer.

Comment: @F505 You are trying to extract from an archive, not create one. I don't think built-in powershell archive functions support gzip. Try asking a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is a one-line equivalent that creates zip archives, and there is even a one-liner to create an exact match, i.e. a tar file. The first place you should look for such a library function is [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/), providing a wealth of high-quality library extensions to PowerShell. Unfortunately, a web-search for a specific item, like your zip creation function, would likely **not** turn up anything because nowhere on the site or in the documentation do they include a list of the cmdlets and functions provided! To find out you have to install the library then do `help about_pscx`. Sifting through that, here is what you will find relevant to your question:

```
Write-Zip
    Create ZIP format archive files from pipline or parameter input. 
Write-GZip
    Create GNU ZIP (GZIP) format files from pipeline or parameter input. 
Write-Tar
    Create Tape Archive (TAR) format files from pipeline or parameter input.
```

And here, from their embedded examples, are how you might use them:

```
PS> dir c:\logs\ -rec -inc *.log | write-zip -level 9 -removeoriginal
PS> dir c:\logs\ -rec -inc *.log | write-tar -output logs.tar | write-gzip -level 9 | move-item c:\archived_logs\
```

Comment: These functions are currently broken in PSCX 2.1 and up. No ETA on fix.